# Hide price range variation on category pages Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a code to move the live variation prices to the top, on the product page, and remove price rangue on product pages and category pages, to display only the lowest price value.

Also need to diplay price tax suffix " IVA inc". This suffix is set on woocommerce configuration.

It works perfectly except that the pre **sale price isn't displayed on categories page**

I'm not a programming expert, i'm making effort to get it work.

Besides this, is it possible to optimize the code?

```
//Move Variations price above variations to have the same template even if variations prices are the same
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 ); 

//Remove Price Range
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'detect_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'detect_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

function detect_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {

// Main Price

$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
if ($prices[0] !== $prices[1] && is_product()) {
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( '', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
}
return $price;
}



add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_min_max_variable_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_min_max_variable_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
    $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );

    $min_price_html = wc_price( $min_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    $price = sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), $min_price_html );

    return $price;
}
```

**The price before the offer sale is not shown on category pages**

[image]

**Product pages works ok**

[image]

Comment: Is your goal just to hide the price shown on the shop / category archive?

Comment: Hi, I need to, hide price range on product pages and category/shop pages. Also, move the selected variation prices to top on product pages. The code I posted, works perfectly on product pages, but the price range is still displaying on category pages. I need to modify it, in order to, hide price range also on category pages.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To hide the price range on the archive/shop pages, you can just override the function

`woocommerce_template_loop_price` which is pluggable. This function lives in /includes/wc-template-functions.php

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_price() {
    // Just do nothing
    return;
}
```

This will however remove all prices from showing on the shop/archive page.

**EDIT**: After the question was updated in the comments, this shows how to ONLY show the minimum variation price for variable products on the Shop/Archive pages.

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_price() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->get_type() == 'variable'){
        echo '<span class="price">' . wc_price($product->get_variation_regular_price('min')) . '</span>';
    } else {
        wc_get_template( 'loop/price.php' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I haven't explained myself well, i want to hide price rangue on category pages, but display the lowest variation value.

Comment: Hi Howard, thanks for the response.
The code works, but I can't get the Price suffix "tax inc" or offer price crossed out next to the actual price.

Comment: Can you post some kind of screen shot? Your question keeps evolving.. maybe you can explain exactly what you're trying to do with a sketch of how you want it to look??

Comment: Hi, i have updated the post with images. I think i have fixed the tax display issue, 
the only thing left is to correct it so that the price before the offer is shown on the category pages. On the product page it is shown.

Comment: So are you saying that instead of the minimum variation price, you actually want the minimum variation sale price shown, with the minimum variation price crossed out?

Comment: Hi, I want to display the left product in the same way that right image product.
The problem with this code is that products with variations doesn't show the  light gray - price without discount- on category pages. Product pages works ok.

It should look like this: [- price without discount-] + [Sale price] + [Tax suffix]

Comment: Did anybody find how to show regular price crossed and display sale price for variable products on archive / category page..